# Unsatisfied dependencies using CDI with Weld when running unit tests on Java SE

Tags: java, cdi, weld, weld-se, weld-junit5

I have a small (Java SE `11.x`) project where I'm testing CDI with Weld. I have these dependencies (among others but these are the relevant ones for this issue):

```
implementation("org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:4.0.0.Final")

runtimeOnly("javax:javaee-api:8.0.1")

testImplementation("org.jboss.weld:weld-junit5:2.0.2.Final")
```

Then I have a simple entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "spell_books")
public final class SpellBook extends AbstractPersistable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  // ...some one-to-many and many-to-may relationships

  public SpellBook() { // No-args constructor required by JPA
    spells = new LinkedList<>();
    wizards = new LinkedList<>();
  }

  public SpellBook(final String name) {
    this();
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void add(final Spell spell) {
    spell.setSpellBook(this);
    spells.add(spell);
  }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPersistable implements Serializable {
  @Version
  @Column(name = "version")
  private Long version;
}
```

...and a DAO class to interface with the database:

```java
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
@Singleton
public class SpellBookDao extends AbstractJpaDao<SpellBook> {
  public Optional<SpellBook> findByName(final String name) {
    logger.debug("Searching spell book with name [{}]...", name);
    final var builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final var criteria = builder.createQuery(clazz);
    final var model = criteria.from(clazz);
    criteria.select(model).where(builder.equal(model.get("name"), name));
    return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.createQuery(criteria.select(model)).getSingleResult());
  }
}

@Log4j2
public abstract class AbstractJpaDao<T extends AbstractPersistable> {
  @PersistenceContext
  protected EntityManager entityManager;

  protected Class<T> clazz;

  public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  // ...some defaults for persist, merge, findAll, findOne, etc.
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to write a simple unit test for the DAO class:

```java
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.acme.service_layer.persistence.SpellBookDao;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.jboss.weld.junit5.EnableWeld;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.UUID;

@EnableWeld
final class SpellBookDaoTest {
  @Inject
  private SpellBookDao dao;

  @Test
  void findByName_WhenSpellBookExists() {
    final var optional = dao.findByName("The Dark Lord Ascending");
    Assertions.assertThat(optional)
        .hasValueSatisfying(it -> {
          Assertions.assertThat(it.getId()).isEqualTo(UUID.fromString("715811c9-ae11-41ec-8652-671fd88cd2a0"));
          Assertions.assertThat(it.getName()).isEqualTo("The Dark Lord Ascending");
          Assertions.assertThat(it.getSpells()).isEmpty();
          Assertions.assertThat(it.getWizards()).isEmpty();
          // ...
          Assertions.assertThat(it.getVersion()).isEqualTo(0L);
        });
  }
}
```

This always fails with this stacktrace:

```sh
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SpellBookDao with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.acme.service_layer.persistence.internal.SpellBookDaoTest.dao
  at org.acme.service_layer.persistence.internal.SpellBookDaoTest.dao(SpellBookDaoTest.java:0)

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SpellBookDao with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.acme.service_layer.persistence.internal.SpellBookDaoTest.dao
  at org.acme.service_layer.persistence.internal.SpellBookDaoTest.dao(SpellBookDaoTest.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)

...many more here
```

I've searched through a lot of similar questions/answers but still, I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong here. Any advice?

By the way, I do have a `main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml` and `test/resources/META-INF/beans.xml`. The content for both is the same:

```xml
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
  <scan>
    <exclude name="org.jboss.weld.**" />
  </scan>
</beans>
```

Comment: Have you tried to configure Weld with `@WeldSetup WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.of(...) etc` ?

Comment: No, what I tried was using `@ExtendWith(WeldJunit5Extension.class)` at class level only because I wanted to be able to inject the dependencies via `@Inject` instead of doing `weld.select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/issues/119#issuecomment-783981429) for this question - this is an issue because as of today (23/02/2021), `weld-junit` version `2.x` is set to work with Java/Jakarta EE 8. I'll need to release a new major version for Jakarta EE 9 and its `jakarta` namespace which is implemented by Weld 4. It shouldn't be too hard and I expect to be able to find time for that within a week or two.

**EDIT:** weld-junit version 3.0.0.Final is now available in Central and is designed to work with Jakarta EE 9 namespaces hence the above issue should be effectively solved.

Until then, you can only use `weld-junit` if you swap to EE 8 with its `javax` namespaces and also use Weld 3 which implements that.

Last but not least, your project mixes up EE 8 and EE 9 artifacts - this is a problem you need to solve on your side, mainly due to the namespace differences between the two, and would keep causing issues even after we fix `weld-junit`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your test with:

```
@ExtendWith(WeldJunit5Extension.class)
final class SpellBookDaoTest {

  @WeldSetup
  WeldInitiator weldInitiator =  WeldInitiator.of(SpellBookDao.class);
```

Add dependency to the API in the gralde config:
`  testImplementation("javax:javaee-api:8.0.1") ``

And your bean will be found.
You've now to provide the EntityManager.

Doc here
https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/blob/master/junit5/README.md
https://weld.cdi-spec.org/news/2017/12/19/weld-meets-junit5/

Comment: I can see this works. But I want to do field injection instead of instantiating the classes programmatically via `weld.select(...).get()`. I'll keep trying to see if I figure it out why is it that it doesn't work as stated in the documentation by just using `@EnableWeld` and `@Inject`. I'll mark your answer as accepted if this cannot be done in such way.

Answer (score 0):

I think CDI can't provide the implementation if you have not annotated at least one with a scoped annotation.
Put @ApplicationScoped or @Singleton on SpellBookDao

Just seen you've already set bean-discovery-mode="all" that should works...

[Edit]

```
Add to your gradle
test.doFirst {
    copy {
        from 'build/resources/main/META-INF/beans.xml'
        into 'build/classes/main/META-INF/'
    }
    copy {
        from 'build/resources/test/META-INF/beans.xml'
        into 'build/classes/test/META-INF/'
    }
}
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/20355024/2710704

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either. I had `@Singleton`, but didn't try with `@ApplicationScoped` until now. It didn't change anything.

Comment: I also tried that when I was searching for questions/answers in SO first. I put a project here: `https://github.com/x80486/javase-cdi-weld/` ...in case you want to give it a whirl.